Getting information of DNS zone security/permission via powershell
I'm trying to obtain the Security information that we can find on this section in Microsoft DNS server console.
DNS Security tab
Using the script below, I'm only able to obtain AD level permisson which does not match to what I see on the console.
    # Get all DNS Zones on the current server
    $zones = Get-DnsServerZone -ComputerName $serverName

    # Loop through each zone to get ACLs
    foreach ($zone in $zones) {
        $zoneDN = "DC=$($zone.ZoneName.Replace('.', ',DC='))"
        Write-Host "Checking ACL in $zoneDN"
        $acl = Get-Acl "AD:$zoneDN" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        
        if ($acl) {
            foreach ($access in $acl.Access) {
                $aclList += [PSCustomObject]@{
                    ServerName          = $serverName
                    ZoneName            = $zone.ZoneName
                    Identity            = $access.IdentityReference
                    AccessControlType   = $access.AccessControlType
                    ActiveDirectoryRights = $access.ActiveDirectoryRights
                    InheritanceType     = $access.InheritanceType
                    IsInherited         = $access.IsInherited
                }
            }
        } else {
            Write-Host "No ACL found for $zoneDN"
        }
    }

Any ideas?

Translating the zone name to a DN will give you the identity of a naming context corresponding to an AD domain partition, not the partition that actually stores the zone information. Use Get-DnsServerDirectoryPartition to get the DNS storage partitions, then translate and search those for the zone information instead

Hi @MathiasR.Jessen thanks for pointing to another way to look up. However, I've found that since the DNS zone is AD integrated, all I need is to get the correct DN. And I'm now able to do it via ADSI edit (not sure if it's do-abel via powershell). Once I get the correct DN, I modify the script to use the correct DN and I get the output that I need (albeit needed to get more things but that can be considered cosmetics)
